# How to show loading icon on RadComboBox Selected Index Changed

Tags: c#, combobox, telerik

I have implemented this demo from telerik 
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/multiplecomboboxes/defaultcs.aspx

I just want the country combobox show Loading icon as in above demo here is my code

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="RoomCategoryID" runat="server" Height="200px" Width="200px" EmptyMessage="Select Category"  
EnableLoadOnDemand="True" MarkFirstMatch="True" CausesValidation="False" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged"
                         ShowMoreResultsBox="True" EnableVirtualScrolling="True">
                         </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

and the other combobox code is

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="SubCategoryID" runat="server" Height="200px" Width="200px" EmptyMessage="Select Sub Category"
    EnableLoadOnDemand="True" MarkFirstMatch="True" CausesValidation="False" 
                             ShowMoreResultsBox="True" EnableVirtualScrolling="True"/>
```

and the event is

```
protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object o, Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
        {
    //This event takes lots of time to load That's why I want Loading icon
    }
```

and ajax setting code is

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server" DefaultLoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1">
                <AjaxSettings>
     <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RoomCategoryID">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="SubCategoryID"/>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="pnlRoomExtra"/>
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
                      </AjaxSettings>
                      </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
              <telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" runat="server" />
```

In my case it is not continent and country they are RoomCategory and RoomSubCategory

Answer (score 1):

Add a `RadScriptManager`Control at the beginning of your form, like this:

```
<telerik:RadScriptManager runat="server" ID="RadScriptManager1" />
```

Then , add both `RadAjaxManager` and `RadAjaxLoadingPanel` control below the `RadScriptManager` Control, as the below:

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server" DefaultLoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1">
        <AjaxSettings>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RoomCategoryID">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="SubCategoryID" />
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        </AjaxSettings>
    </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
    <telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" runat="server" />
```

Comment: I already had this code I forgot to mention in my quest please review my edited question again thanks

Comment: Maybe try to remove the line that includes pnlRoomExtra from the AjaxUpdatedControl. Also check if there are any javascript errors occurring on your page.